# How to know what coin has been exchanged through Web3 Api

Tags: web3js, transactions, web3.py

Is there a way to know what coin and how much of it has been exchanged when getting a transaction history through the Web3 API?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a transaction, you can read the details and extract out the call parameters. You'll need to know the function layout to reverse engineer the details you know.

Comment: That's what I'm doing but I need to find the contracts ABI each time. Thinking if there is a way to do it automatically through web3 (without calling the Etherscan API.)

Comment: There's no standard way, because there's no standard in how exchanges are implemented.

If the transaction emits any events, you could listen to those. Otherwise, you'll have to do your best to reverse engineer it.